# jQuery - .get() issue with IE7,8,9

Tags: php, jquery, html

I testing send and receive data to php file with jQuery and I have an issue with IE(Im using IE9 but I checked with IE8 and IE7)

when I click in on of my div I send to the server an "ID" and the PHP file return the answer back, its work and the jQuery is showing the result in other Div and in alert msg.

The issue start when i change the code in the received php file, if I click again in one of my divs, the jQuery showing the same msg even I change the code and the replay msg is different now.

This problem solved when I close and reopen the IE.

This issue doesn't happen with firefox and chrome, does anyone have any idea ?

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>test</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
              $(function(){
                $('.user').click(function(){
                    var id_value = $(this).data('friendid');
                    $.get('test1.php', {id: id_value}, function(data) {
                        $('#show').html(data);
                        alert(data);
                    });
                })
            })

   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="user"  data-friendid="1">
    <img src='webimgs/nopf.jpg' alt="test" />
    <h4>&nbsp;fullname</h4>
    <br />
 </div>
 <div class="user"  data-friendid="2">
    <img src='webimgs/nopf.jpg' alt="test2"/>
    <h4>&nbsp;fullname</h4>
    <br />
 </div>
 <div id="show" style="color:red">
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and the PHP file:

```
<?php
if ($_GET["id"]==1) { echo "you choose number is " . $_GET["id"].", thanks." ; }
?>
```

Comment: If you're already using jQuery, why aren't you doing `$(this).data('friendid')` instead?

Comment: You right, I changed but this is no what solves the problem, any idea ?

Comment: This sounds like an AJAX caching problem. Try using `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})` to bust the cache, before the `$.get()` call is made.

Comment: Now it is work, it was AJAX caching problem. thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Thank to  "Boaz" I use `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})` and its fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .get method can be cached depending on browser setup. If you use the .post method it will prevent caching of data on the browser side.

Referenced from http://www.sitepoint.com/key-differences-post/

Characteristics of GET:

- Use GET for safe actions and POST for unsafe actions.
- **GET requests can be cached**
- GET requests can remain in the browser history
- GET requests can be bookmarked
- GET requests can be distributed & shared
- GET requests can be hacked